# Variables largas por URL

Tags: php, ajax, url

Estoy creando un sitio web de lecturas pero sucede que al enviar por la URL el contenido de un TextArea es muy largo y me devuelve un error 414 el navegador, estoy usando PHP con AJAX

Este es el campo TextArea:

```
   <textarea id="I_Contenido" class="materialize-textarea"></textarea>
```

En el Javascript asi lo recupero:

```
var Contenido =document.getElementById("I_Contenido").value;
```

Lo envia al php de esta manera:

```
  xmlhttp.open("POST","../Entities/addLectura.php?Titulo="+Titulo+"&Descripcion="+Descripcion+"&Autor="+Autor+"&Imagen="+Imagen+"&Fecha="+Fecha+"&Contenido="+Contenido,true);
```

Y en PHP lo recupero asi:

```
$Contenido = ($_GET['Contenido']);
```

¿Alguna idea de como podria comprimir el texto o hacer que me lo permita enviar ?

Comment: Si el método `post` ,no tendría por qué añadir los parámetros y sus respectivos valores por medio de la `URL` , además tampoco tendría sentido obtener desde `PHP` con `$_GET` cuando la petición es `POST`.

Comment: Creo que ya lo he solucionado, es verdad, no tiene sentido usarlo de esta manera, lo envie por post, solo agregue un Form y quedo funcionando, Gracias por la respuesta

Answer (score 1):

Quedo corregido, lo que hice es usar un form y enviarlo por POST a el archivo PHP donde hago la inserción a la base de Datos, igual en la base cambie el campo por longtext

Answer (score 1):

Efectivamente, la mejor opción, ademas de transparente para el usuario, es siempre intentar usar envío de métodos por POST, si tenemos que enviar muchos parámetros lo ideal es montar un array e incluso trabajar con JSON, fáciles de usar con JS y con PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Bajo Apache, el límite es un valor configurable en el valor [limitrequestLine](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#limitrequestline) en el archivo /etc/apache2/apache2.conf.

No obstante en muchas ocasiones no tenemos posibilidad de alterar este valor, bien sea porque nuestro sistema está en un dominio compartido, nuestro administrador no nos autoriza... u otras causas, es buena idea 
la propuesta de Jorge Peinado y tratar de enviarlo por $_POST

Espero haber podido ayudar.
Saludos